# Customize view paths .net core 2.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, razor-pages

I'm trying to configure my core application to add the solution name to the name/path of all views when it compiles/precompiles:

**Original**: `Views/Home/index.cshtml`

**what I want is**: `MyApplicationName/Views/Home/index.cshtml`

I found a few articles including one from Samuele that explains on how to do this in core 1.0 [here](https://samueleresca.net/2016/07/net-core-1-0-customize-view-paths/), but I need to do it for core 2.1.

Any one has a solution for this or found some article for core 2.1?

Answer (score 0):

In your `Startup` class you can manage routes in your app

As I understand you want to change the root folder `Views`

The code below changes the root folder from the default `Views` to `MyApplicationName:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
  services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options => {
    options.RootDirectory = "/MyApplicationName";
  });
}
```